# Can google adwords conversion tracking be implemented with a backend integration?

Tags: google-ads-api

We're setting up adwords tracking at the moment, but one of the requirements is that we let adwords optimise based on our net earnings figures, which only our backend is aware of. For google analytics, we send these figures via the data measurement protocol. Is there something similar to use for adwords? Or what is the approach given those requirements?

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/conversion-tracking

I've seen there's offline conversion tracking here: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2998031?hl=en

But if my understanding is correct, this will require some manual work. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in an automated way?

Comment: Did you every figure out a solution to this?  I am currently looking to do the same thing.